# How in livewire use route by its name?

Tags: laravel-routing, laravel-livewire

In my laravel 7 /livewire 1.3 / turbolinks:5 / alpine@v2 app I have route defined

```
Route::livewire('/hostel/{slug}', 'hostel.hostel-view-page')->name('hostel-view-page');
```

When I use it :

```
<a href="{{ route('hostel-view-page', $hostelsIsHomepageSpotlight->slug)  }}" >
    Title
</a>
```

it does not work as reactive, as all page is reloaded. I prefer to name of this route, not like :

```
<a href="/hostel/{{ $hostelsIsHomepageSpotlight->slug }}" >
    Title
</a>
```

Which is a valid way ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, it works well for me:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin',
        'as' => 'admin.',
        'middleware' => 'your:middleware',
], function () {
    Route::livewire('your-url-here', 'your-livewire-class-here')
    ->name('whatever.you.want');
});
```